# How do I add a Textbox in a menu in Visual Studio 2010 addin?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, textbox, add-in

I would like to add a texbox to the Project,Item and solution menu in Visual Studio 2010.
It seems the way I did it in Visual Studio 2008 no longer work.

Old way:
menuItem = _applicationObject.GetCommandBar("item").Controls.Add(MsoControlType.msoControlEdit, 1, "", 1, false);

Is there a way of doing this in Visual Studio 2010? Doing the above code returns that I can only add popup and button.

Cheers
/Jimmy

Comment: Hi Jimmy,

I think that is not possible to add textbox in the project menu.

Comment: Thats the only answer I seem to find also =( Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately that can't be done in Visual Studio 2010.